# JPA use with hundreds of servers

Tags: java, database, jpa

I have never used JPA but I am wondering if it is possible to configure it in a way that it will connect to around 200 different servers but input the exact same data into a database on each server all with the same structure.

Comment: Do you mean a single database replicated in 199 servers or 200 different databases?

Comment: Aren't you looking for something like a master/slave replication setup? A problem that I'd rather leave to the DB software than to JPA. Some context wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Imagine 200 file servers in 200 different locations. Yes it is a single database replicated at all locations. When I want to insert data I want to insert it to all 200 different locations. I'm open to ideas. Right now I use basic JDBC and loop through the server addresses. The servers are running MSSQL server.

Comment: I'm afraid that a manual loop over all the servers will sooner or later cause you serious headaches (related to a consistent state of these servers). What happens when a server is unreachable, are you going to be able to later execute all the statements it missed? There are replication solutions for MSSQL, look into these.

Comment: We have service that distributes data to each of the servers but we are seeing discrepancies at the servers (Data missing). My application is simply a maintenance application that allows us to add the missing data when a problem is reported. I was hoping for a better solution than what I currently have until we resolve the issue of the data not making it to every server. I do use an service to process these query tasks and it does store queries that did not succeed and will retry when you order it to. I do store these in memory at the moment but plan to move to XML or something.

Comment: How about jms topic and 200listeners? I agree with others, replication isn't easy thing to get right.

Comment: @Ruinous What you are describing is very odd to me. Why don't you manage replications at the database level and leave that concern out of the application scope? Today's all major RDBMS are designed with some form of horizontal scaling in mind. At least that way your application (JPA/JDBC) is wholly abstracted from your database architecture and you won't have to implement loops of hell to ensure consistency. True ACIDicity is hard enough to ensure at the rdbms level. Any attempt to implement an inhouse bypass strategy would be a very rough ride and a nightmare to test.

Comment: @SamiKorhonen We have that system coming in 3 months or so but this is just a temporary maintenance tool.

Comment: @okiharaherbst This is just a temporary maintenance tool until we implement the message queue middleware in the coming months. The databases are extremely out of sync and although we add missing data as it is reported I just wanted a better way of submitting the data rather than the current system.

Comment: Is this case close or do you need more input?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question lacks important contextual information I dare to answer (what seems to be) the core of it:

> ...JPA...possible configure it in a way that it will connect to around 200 different
>   servers...

No, not really. The foundation of a JPA setup is a single data source i.e. connection to one server.

As others have correctly pointed out you attempt to solve your problem on OS or data base level. Depending on what you really need what you want to look into is:

- database replication
- database mirroring
- database clustering (may be a form of either of the first two)

Primer for MS SQL: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151799.aspx